# NestedScrollView inside ConstraintLayout not scrollable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `ConstraintLayout` and inside it a couple other sections that are also `ConstraintLayout`s. Finally at the bottom I have two `RecyclerView`s and a pair of buttons. My goal is to have the part of the screen below `layout_2` scrollable - so that includes two `RecyclerView`s with a couple of accompanying labels. And then the two buttons have to be visible at all times.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/picker_performance_grey"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <!--        some widgets-->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_1">

        <!--        some widgets-->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--            some widgets-->

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_pick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                tools:listitem="@layout/inbound_item_detail_sector"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <!--            some widgets-->

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_buffer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                tools:listitem="@layout/inbound_item_detail_sector"
                tools:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            style="@style/button_bordered"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="50" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_2"
            style="@style/button_bordered"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="@string/product_detail_btn_finish" />

    </LinearLayout>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, the scrolling doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try to stop nestedScrolling in recyclerview for ex

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_pick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                tools:listitem="@layout/inbound_item_detail_sector"
                tools:visibility="visible" />
```

or from the code `rv_pick.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

also if only one recycler will appear and the other one will be gone i suggest to use only one in the XML and control it from the java code by changing the adapter

Comment: Tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work.